# Update Table1 where column in Table2 IS NULL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to add a new record to Table1 with Info from Table2, only where a column in Table2 is null.

So Say Table2 has 3 records, only 1 has a null value in Column 2.  I want Column 1 and 3 information from Table2 to be added as new record into table1, but only for that 1 record.

I cannot use INSERT into and WHERE together, can anyone suggest an alternative?  I was thinking about creating a temp table, adding all records from table2, deleting the ones that are not null (I think I can do that) leaving only the record I want to add, which I can then do using the Insert into.

It feel like the long way around and as I am still a begginer so I wonder if I am not missing something.  Just FYI I am using VBA to run the SQL, but cannot figure out what to use to provide any code.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want insert/select:

```
insert into table1 ( . . . )  -- list columns here
    select col1, col3
    from table2
    where col2 is null;
```